# ¿Cómo detectar teclas presionadas en editor WYSIWYG tinyMCE? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea, tinymce, onkeyup, wysiwyg

Lo que he intentado con JS es lo siguiente:

```
let validarTextareas = document.querySelectorAll(".tox-edit-area__iframe");

    let textAreasVacios = 0;

    /* Intentando Capturar teclas presionadas en tiyMCE
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    let valorEscritoTextArea = elemento.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(
        "#tinymce"
    )[0];

    valorEscritoTextArea.forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.onkeyup = () => {
            console.log("tecla presionada");
        };
    });

    /*
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    validarTextareas.forEach((elemento) => {
        valorActualTextArea = elemento.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(
            "#tinymce"
        )[0].innerHTML;

        console.log(valorActualTextArea);

        if (valorActualTextArea === "<p><br></p>") {
            textAreasVacios++;
        }
    });
```

Con el código de arriba consigo obtener el contenido del editor, pero no detectar cuando el usuario escribe. Si existe una manera más fácil para obtener los valores de varios editores o uno pues agreadecería conocerla

tinyMCE se inica en uno o más textareas con la siguiente estructura (ignorar variables), el selector son todas las etiquetas textareas:

```
<textarea class="textAreapunto" numtextareasubpunto="${numTextareapunto}" numSubpunto="${numSubpunto}"><p></p></textarea>
```

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.